# How do people have long segmented web pages?

Tags: html, css

I apologise in advance if this is a really obvious and noobish question, but how do i segment a web page into multiple portions, with each portion of the webpage filling the screen in it's entirety?

A good example of what i wish to do would be similar to treehouse's homepage when i segment the webpage into multiple portions e.g "home","about us", etc.. I've tried right clicking on the webpage and having a look through the css but did not see height and/or width applied to anything on the page.

How exactly does treehouse, and others segment their webpages?Do they simply make use of a background image or is there some other method of doing so?

Comment: what is your exact question? How a full screen background-image for each segment is possible or how you can create multiple full-screen elements? Here is a simple demo of how you can create full-screen elements http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/ngjLh/ (p.s. i did not downvote you- either way your question does not contain any code samples of your actual problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give the html, body elements a the css property's:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

And in your html you makke a couple of div's like this:

```
<div class="fitScreen">
   content 1
</div>

<div class="fitScreen" style="background-color: red">
   content 2
</div>

<div class="fitScreen" style="background-color: blue">
   content 3
</div>

<div class="fitScreen" style="background-color: yellow">
  content 4
</div>
```

And you give them a css property of `height: 100%;` They fill the whole screen.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/FH3gn/)

EDIT:

Or if you just want 1 element that fills the screen, and all that is beneath that element has a height of auto, just just give make one `div` with the class of `fitScreen`.

And beneath that another element with your own content.